# Desktop Safari - Set <audio> src as blob with js

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-audio

I'm trying to set the src of an audio tag with JS(Angular, but i'm using native JS to do so).
I'm getting the file as BLOB for security reasons.
I'm doing this in order to set the src:

```
scope.data.createAudioUrl().then(
    (createAudioUrl) => {
      var player = document.getElementById("audio-#{scope.data.messageId}")
      player.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(createAudioUrl)
      $timeout(
        () => {
          player.play()
        }
        , 0
      )
     }
  )
```

Chrome + Firefox works like a charm. Safari doesn't...
Does Safari support BLOB in the audio/video tag?
If so how can i get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

you use ng-src like this :

```
<audio ng-src="audio_url" controls></audio>

scope.data.createAudioUrl().then(
(createAudioUrl) => {

      audio_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(createAudioUrl)
      $timeout(
        () => {
          player.play()
        }
        , 0
      )
}
```

don't forget to attach `audio_url`  to your scope.

Comment: That won't work either. Have you tested it using BLOB ?